# lstinputlisting shows wrong number in reference

Tags: cross-referencing, listings

I'm pretty new to LaTeX, so please be a little patiently with me.

So here is my problem:

I got some text and there i want to reference a little bit code shown in the next line.

What i tried so far:

**Variante 1:**

Im Quellcodausschnitt`~\ref{lst:product_xml}` ist zu sehen, dass drei Attribute definiert wurden.

```
\lstinputlisting
    [caption={Übergeordneter Knoten Product}
      \label{lst:product_xml},
      firstline=2, lastline=2,
      language=XML]
  {code/product_xml.xml}
```

the output looks just fine with one exception, there is the wrong number behind Quellcodausschnitt

> Quellcodausschnitt 2

but the caption says

> Code 4.1: Übergeordneter Knoten Product

**Variante 2**

```
\lstinputlisting
    [caption={Übergeordneter Knoten Product}
      label={lst:product_xml},
      firstline=2, lastline=2,
      language=XML]{code/product_xml.xml}
```

i found that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47269/104758)

Outcome was:

> Quellcodausschnitt ??

i don't want to use

```
\begin{lstlisting}
Put your code here.
\end{lstlisting}
```

cause i want to load some more lines from that file.
so the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122282/reference-to-a-listing-returns-wrong-number) is not an option for me

**full document:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[savemem]{listings}
\lstloadlanguages{TeX}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}

\definecolor{lbcolor}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=5pt,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    breakautoindent=true,
    postbreak=\space,
    tabsize=2,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lbcolor}}

\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  morestring=[s]{"}{"},
  morecomment=[s]{?}{?},
  morecomment=[s]{!--}{--},
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  moredelim=[s][\color{black}]{>}{<},
  moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{\ }{=},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{maroon}
}

\begin{document}

%  \lstlistoflistings 

  Im Quellcodausschnitt~\ref{lst:product_xml} ist zu sehen, dass drei Attribute definiert wurden

\lstinputlisting
    [caption={Übergeordneter Knoten Product} %!!!! i did a great mistakte here i forgot to set a comma at the end of the line
      label={lst:product_xml},
      firstline=2, lastline=2,
      language=XML]{product_xml.xml}


\end{document}
```

is there a way to fix this, or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you compile twice? If this does not solve the problem, post the complete code, not just fragments only? I also think it should be `label={...}` here for `listings`

Comment: what do you mean by not just fragments? the only thing that i left out was the header.tex, cause it's a bit to long / i let kile compile, should i compile via terminal?

Comment: Casting the fragments into something compilable it provides the correct reference number after two compilations

Comment: It's a fragment: I only could check for myself because I have a scratch document on my disk here posting your fragment and running. Other users might don't have this and new users do not profit from such lines only. The usual way to post here is to reduce the document to the absolute minium version that still shows the issue. We also don't have your `.xml` file at hand, that it's read by the `lstinputlisting` command, so compilation would fail again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: Compile twice and the reference is showing up correctly.

Use the `label=` key of the `\lstinputlisting` command to provide the label name, not something like `\caption...\label`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}


Im Quellcodausschnitt~\ref{lst:product_xml} ist zu sehen, dass drei Attribute definiert wurden

\lstinputlisting[caption={Übergeordneter Knoten Product},
label={lst:product_xml},
%firstline=2, lastline=2,
language=C]
{helloworld.c}
%  {code/product_xml.xml}

\end{document}
```

And the `helloworld.c` file:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, the comma after the caption did the trick, but still, why can't i use the `\label{lst:...}` command? it works for figures just fine

Comment: @Mofty: This is a different setup -- `listings` is a floating environment, but uses a different `\caption` mechanism. That's why it is `caption=...` and `label=...`